# Laravel Rest API: How to implement a function for post request

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, rest, laravel-5

I am trying to implement a REST API for basic CRUD operations with Laravel 5.4
I have a post method as below.

```
public function storeReport(StoreReportRequest $request){

    $inputs = $request->only('company_name',
                             'company_experience',
                             'service_start_time',
                             'service_end_time',
                             'latitude',
                             'longitude',
                             'additional_info',
                             'user_id'
                             );

    //save image content to folder and image name to database
    $image = $request->file('picture');
    $fileName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $image->storeAs('images', $fileName);
    $inputs['picture_url'] = $fileName;

    $report = Report::create($inputs);

    return 'success';
}
```

I do not have any problems with storing the data.I have some rules for validation and i do validation via `StoreReportRequest` class.What i want to learn is how can i handle the response after POST request. For example if validation fails or any exception occurs what should i return and how it should be. I have done some research but couldnt find any proper answers. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To be honest, its kind of up to you. You may want a 422 response status code and the validation errors from your validator but it totally depends on how you wish to consume your REST API.

Comment: @Jamesking56 as a newbie i am just wondering what would be the best practice

Comment: Its purely a matter of opinion. In my point of view, a good idea would be to follow @Sandeesh 's answer of using a 422 status code and adding your validation errors as the response content. Something like `{success: false, errors: [ <Laravel Validator Errors array> ]}`. Then clients can detect the 422 status code and then view the content to see specifically what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I normally do a response in json wich is always easy to parse, on the end of your function if everything was correctly done you can do this:

```
return response()->json(["response" => true]);
```

and if failed for some reason

```
return response()->json(["response" => false, errors => ["This can be an array or whatever"]  ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The validation will return a json response with the error messages with a status code of 422. So you don't have to worry about the validation failure exceptions.

As for what you want to do after creating the report is upto you. You could return a json response with the newly created report or send a success message with the status code 200 (set by default).

Laravel does most of the work for you and you just need to define the responses based on your API requirements.